# Does the Android x86 have support OPEN GLES 2.0?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, andengine, android-x86

Does the Android x86 have support OPEN GLES 2.0 ?
i run AndEngine GLES 2 example on Android x86 virtual machine but i get an messenger : force stopped !
Log Cat :

> No eglconfig found

So, Anybody answer this question for me ?
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

yes it should support it.
you need to use the 4.0.3 image or higher.
If that's already the case, you should check that you have the proper OpenGL drivers on your system for your GPU.

And don't forget to tick the "use Host GPU" option in the AVD properties if you're using the Android SDK Emulator:

[image: AVD settings]